# CUDA performance issue

Tags: performance, cuda, gpu

I really have no idea how to name the problem i've run into, so any mod rename it accordingly if you think so.

I got the following matrix vector multiplication kernel:

```
__global__ void dmv_gpu_shmem(const value_t *a, const value_t *x, value_t *y,
                              size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ value_t shmem_buf[];
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    int gtid = get_global_tid();
    value_t _y = 0.0;

    if (gtid > n) 
        return;

    int last_id = n/blockDim.x;

    for(size_t j=0; j< last_id; j++) {

        shmem_buf[ltid] = x[blockDim.x*j + ltid];
        __syncthreads();

        for(size_t i=0; i< blockDim.x; i++) {
            _y += a[gtid + (i + j*blockDim.x)*n] * shmem_buf[i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    y[gtid] = _y;

}
```

I have to test this kernel for quite some blocksizes, but the timing results i got where not that good. So i decided to modify this in the following manner, and fix the blocksize to 32 when calling the kernel

```
__global__ void dmv_gpu_shmem(const value_t *a, const value_t *x, value_t *y,
                              size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ value_t shmem_buf[];
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    int gtid = get_global_tid();
    value_t _y = 0.0;

    if (gtid > n) 
        return;

    int last_id = n/32;

    for(size_t j=0; j< last_id; j++) {

        shmem_buf[ltid] = x[32*j + ltid];
        __syncthreads();

        for(size_t i=0; i< 32; i++) {
            _y += a[gtid + (i + j*32)*n] * shmem_buf[i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    y[gtid] = _y;

}
```

To my great surprise the kernel got multiple times better in terms of execution time, and i have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Can someone more experienced explain this?

Also given this situation, how am i supposed to get the max out of my kernel using all the different blocksizes i want? I can't do this thing for all the blocksizes...

Edit:

This should be a working repro case:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cublas_v2.h" //CUBLAS LIBRARY

#ifndef VALUES_MAX
#   define VALUES_MAX 1.
#endif

#ifndef EPS
#   define EPS 1.e-6
#endif

#ifndef NR_ITER
#   define NR_ITER 200
#endif

enum
{
    GPU_NAIVE = 0,
    GPU_COALESCED,
    GPU_SHMEM,
    GPU_KERNEL_END
};

void *gpu_alloc(size_t count)
{
    void *ret;
    if (cudaMalloc(&ret, count) != cudaSuccess) {
        ret = NULL;
    }

    return ret;
}

int copy_to_gpu(const void *host, void *gpu, size_t count)
{
    if (cudaMemcpy(gpu, host, count, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

int copy_from_gpu(void *host, const void *gpu, size_t count)
{
    if (cudaMemcpy(host, gpu, count, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) != cudaSuccess)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

void mat_init_rand(float **a, size_t n, float max)
{
    size_t  i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                {
                    //printf("%d %d \n", i, j);
                    a[i][j] = 2 * (((float) drand48()) - 0.5) * max;
                }
        }
}

void vec_init(float *v, size_t n, float val)
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            v[i] = val;
        }
}

void vec_init_rand(float *v, size_t n, float max)
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            v[i] = 2 * (((float) drand48()) - 0.5) * max;
        }
}

void vec_print(const float *v, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%f \n", v[i]);
}


void **calloc_2d(size_t n, size_t m, size_t size)
{
    char    **ret = (char **) malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    if (ret) {
        char    *area = (char *) calloc(n*m, size);
        if (area) {
            for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                ret[i] = (char *) &area[i*m*size];
        } else {
            free(ret);
            ret = NULL;
        }
    }

    return (void **) ret;
}

void **copy_2d(void **dst, const void **src, size_t n, size_t m, size_t size)
{
    memcpy(dst[0], src[0], n*m*size);
    return dst;
}

void free_2d(void **array)
{
    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
}

__global__ void dmv_gpu_shmem(const float *a, const float *x, float *y,
                              size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ float shmem_buf[];
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    int gtid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    float _y = 0.0;

    if (gtid > n) 
        return;

    int last_id = n/blockDim.x;

    for(size_t j=0; j< last_id; j++) {

        shmem_buf[ltid] = x[blockDim.x*j + ltid];
        __syncthreads();

        for(size_t i=0; i< blockDim.x; i++) {
            _y += a[gtid + (i + j*blockDim.x)*n] * shmem_buf[i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    y[gtid] = _y;

}

__global__ void dmv_gpu_shmem_static(const float *a, const float *x, float *y,
                              size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ float shmem_buf[];
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    int gtid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    float _y = 0.0;

    if (gtid > n) 
        return;

    int last_id = n/32;

    for(size_t j=0; j< last_id; j++) {

        shmem_buf[ltid] = x[32*j + ltid];
        __syncthreads();

        for(size_t i=0; i< 32; i++) {
            _y += a[gtid + (i + j*32)*n] * shmem_buf[i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    y[gtid] = _y;

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Wrong arguments \n");
        return -1;

    }

    size_t orig_n = atoi(argv[1]);

    /* Read block size and kernel to launch from the environment */
    const char *env_gpu_kernel = getenv("GPU_KERNEL");
    const char *env_gpu_block_size = getenv("GPU_BLOCK_SIZE");
    int kernel = (env_gpu_kernel) ? atoi(env_gpu_kernel) : GPU_NAIVE;
    int block_size = (env_gpu_block_size) ? atoi(env_gpu_block_size) : 256;

    //Adjust Matrix to fit blocksize
    size_t n = ((orig_n - 1)/block_size + 1)*block_size;
    int grid_size = (n-1)/block_size + 1; 

    printf("Matrix size: %zd\n", orig_n);
    printf("Input Block size: %zd\n", block_size);
    printf("Adjusted matrix size: %zd\n", n);

    /*
     * Allocate the structures.
     * 
     * Initialization to zero is crucial if you adjusted the matrix
     * size.
     */
    float **A = (float **) calloc_2d(n, n, sizeof(**A));
    float *x = (float *) calloc(n, sizeof(*x));
    float *y = (float *) calloc(n, sizeof(*y));

    /* Initialize */
    srand48(0);
    mat_init_rand(A, orig_n, VALUES_MAX);
    vec_init_rand(x, orig_n, VALUES_MAX);

    vec_init(y, orig_n, 0.0);


    printf("Setup Complete\n");

    /*
     *  FILLME: Set up the blocks, grid and shared memory depending on
     *          the kernel. Make any transformations to the input
     *          matrix here.
     */ 

    //Transposing Matrix for Shared and Coalesced Matrices
    float tmp;
    for(size_t i=0;i<n;i++) 
        for(size_t j=i+1;j<n;j++) {

            tmp=A[i][j];
            A[i][j] = A[j][i];
            A[j][i] = tmp;
        }

    dim3 gpu_block(block_size, 1);   // Number of threads 
    dim3 gpu_grid(grid_size, 1);    //  Number of blocks
    size_t shmem_size = 0;          //  Shared memory size
    /* Set SHARED MEMORY size */
    shmem_size = block_size * sizeof(float);

    printf(">>>> Begin of record <<<<\n");
    printf("Block size: %dx%d\n", gpu_block.x, gpu_block.y);
    printf("Grid size : %dx%d\n", gpu_grid.x, gpu_grid.y);
    printf("Shared memory size: %ld bytes\n", shmem_size);

    /* GPU allocations */
    float *gpu_A = (float *) gpu_alloc(n*n*sizeof(*gpu_A));
    float *gpu_x = (float *) gpu_alloc(n*sizeof(*gpu_x));
    float *gpu_y = (float *) gpu_alloc(n*sizeof(*gpu_y));

    /* Copy data to GPU */
    copy_to_gpu(A[0], gpu_A, n*n*sizeof(*gpu_A));
    copy_to_gpu(x, gpu_x, n*sizeof(*gpu_x)); 

    /* Reset y and copy it to GPU */
    vec_init(y, n, 0.0);
    copy_to_gpu(y, gpu_y, n*sizeof(*gpu_y));


    dmv_gpu_shmem<<<gpu_grid,gpu_block,shmem_size>>>
        (gpu_A, gpu_x, gpu_y, n);

    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess)
        printf("gpu kernel failed to launch \n");

    dmv_gpu_shmem_static<<<gpu_grid,gpu_block,shmem_size>>>
        (gpu_A, gpu_x, gpu_y, n);

    if (cudaGetLastError() != cudaSuccess)
        printf("gpu kernel failed to launch \n");


    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    /* Free resources on host */
    free_2d((void **) A);
    free(x);
    free(y);

    /* Free resources on GPU */
    cudaFree(gpu_A);
    cudaFree(gpu_x);
    cudaFree(gpu_y);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile with

```
nvcc dmv_test_case.cu
```

Execute with

```
 GPU_KERNEL=2 GPU_BLOCK_SIZE=32 ./a.out 2048
```

GPU_KERNEL variable does nothing in this case.
GPU_BLOCK_SIZE is obvious.
The number argument is the size of the vector (n) and the matrix size (nxn)

Comment: Probably compiler optimisation because of the fixed loop count. A complete repro case would be helpful, however.

Comment: Doesn't nvcc do automatic optimisation on the kernels, i think i read this in the programming guide. I'll try to make a repro, but its too hard since the whole program is again split in 5 files...

Comment: Yes, but the loops can be unrolled in the second kernel and not in the first because of the constant trip counts.

Comment: And this is something that can be controlled from the compiler? Only a pragma controls the unrolling doesn't it?

Comment: Just added a minimum working example, please check it out.

Comment: I don't understand your example. It only contains one of the kernels, and the kernel you have included is different from the kernel code you originally posted. Despite adding almost 400 lines (that is far too much, BTW), you still haven't managed to provide code for both kernel versions which I could compile and disassemble.

Comment: @talonmies sorry, i messed up, tried to fix it quickly. It should be fine now. I removed all the timers as well just to make up some more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone more experienced explain this?

A full analysis is beyond the scope of what I'm prepared to offer, but I'll start you partway down the path.  As @talonmies indicated, this is at least partly due to "compiler optimization due to fixed trip counts".

When I run your code with `nvprof --print-gpu-trace ...`, I observe about a 3x difference in kernel execution time between the two kernels (on a cc2.0 device).   There might be some skew in this, because we're calling the "faster" kernel after the "slower" kernel  - but it's operating on the same data, so there may be some caching benefit by being second.  But let's ignore that.  Let's take a look at the SASS code output from `cuobjdump -sass` for your code:

slower kernel:

```
        Function : _Z13dmv_gpu_shmemPKfS0_Pfm
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
/*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
....
....
/*01f0*/         LD.E R18, [R2];                                   /* 0x8400000000249c85 */
/*01f8*/         IADD R19.CC, R19, 0x1;                            /* 0x4801c0000534dc03 */
/*0200*/         LDS R17, [R21];                                   /* 0xc100000001545c85 */
/*0208*/         IADD.X R20, R20, RZ;                              /* 0x48000000fd451c43 */
/*0210*/         ISUB RZ.CC, R19, c[0x0][0x8];                     /* 0x48014000213fdd03 */
/*0218*/         IADD R21, R21, 0x4;                               /* 0x4800c00011555c03 */
/*0220*/         ISETP.LT.U32.X.AND P0, PT, R20, RZ, PT;           /* 0x188e0000fd41dc43 */
/*0228*/         IADD R2.CC, R2, R15;                              /* 0x480100003c209c03 */
/*0230*/         IADD.X R3, R3, R16;                               /* 0x480000004030dc43 */
/*0238*/         FFMA R6, R18, R17, R6;                            /* 0x300c000045219c00 */
/*0240*/     @P0 BRA 0x1f0;                                        /* 0x4003fffea00001e7 */
```

faster "static" kernel:

```
        Function : _Z20dmv_gpu_shmem_staticPKfS0_Pfm
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
/*0000*/         MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];                            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */
....
....
/*0110*/         LD.E R10, [R2];                                   /* 0x8400000000229c85 */
/*0118*/         STS [R6], R10;                                    /* 0xc900000000629c85 */
/*0120*/         BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ, RZ, PT;                      /* 0x50ee0000ffffdc04 */
/*0128*/         LD.E R22, [R8];                                   /* 0x8400000000859c85 */
/*0130*/         IADD R10.CC, R8, R14;                             /* 0x4801000038829c03 */
/*0138*/         IADD.X R11, R9, R15;                              /* 0x480000003c92dc43 */
/*0140*/         IADD R18.CC, R10, R14;                            /* 0x4801000038a49c03 */
/*0148*/         LD.E R21, [R10];                                  /* 0x8400000000a55c85 */
/*0150*/         IADD.X R19, R11, R15;                             /* 0x480000003cb4dc43 */
/*0158*/         IADD R16.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039241c03 */
/*0160*/         LD.E R24, [R18];                                  /* 0x8400000001261c85 */
/*0168*/         IADD.X R17, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d345c43 */
/*0170*/         LDS.128 R8, [RZ];                                 /* 0xc100000003f21cc5 */
/*0178*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0180*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*0188*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*0190*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*0198*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*01a0*/         LD.E R23, [R18];                                  /* 0x840000000125dc85 */
/*01a8*/         FFMA R8, R22, R8, R20;                            /* 0x3028000021621c00 */
/*01b0*/         LD.E R22, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001059c85 */
/*01b8*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*01c0*/         FFMA R8, R21, R9, R8;                             /* 0x3010000025521c00 */
/*01c8*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*01d0*/         IADD R16.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039441c03 */
/*01d8*/         FFMA R8, R24, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029821c00 */
/*01e0*/         LD.E R24, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001461c85 */
/*01e8*/         IADD.X R17, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d545c43 */
/*01f0*/         FFMA R26, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d969c00 */
/*01f8*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0200*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x10];                               /* 0xc100000043f21cc5 */
/*0208*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*0210*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*0218*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*0220*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*0228*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*0230*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*0238*/         FFMA R26, R22, R8, R26;                           /* 0x3034000021669c00 */
/*0240*/         LD.E R22, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001059c85 */
/*0248*/         FFMA R8, R23, R9, R26;                            /* 0x3034000025721c00 */
/*0250*/         LD.E R23, [R18];                                  /* 0x840000000125dc85 */
/*0258*/         IADD R16.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039441c03 */
/*0260*/         IADD.X R17, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d545c43 */
/*0268*/         FFMA R8, R24, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029821c00 */
/*0270*/         LD.E R24, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001461c85 */
/*0278*/         FFMA R26, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d969c00 */
/*0280*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0288*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x20];                               /* 0xc100000083f21cc5 */
/*0290*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*0298*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*02a0*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*02a8*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*02b0*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*02b8*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*02c0*/         FFMA R26, R22, R8, R26;                           /* 0x3034000021669c00 */
/*02c8*/         LD.E R22, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001059c85 */
/*02d0*/         FFMA R8, R23, R9, R26;                            /* 0x3034000025721c00 */
/*02d8*/         LD.E R23, [R18];                                  /* 0x840000000125dc85 */
/*02e0*/         IADD R16.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039441c03 */
/*02e8*/         IADD.X R17, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d545c43 */
/*02f0*/         FFMA R8, R24, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029821c00 */
/*02f8*/         LD.E R24, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001461c85 */
/*0300*/         FFMA R26, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d969c00 */
/*0308*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0310*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x30];                               /* 0xc1000000c3f21cc5 */
/*0318*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*0320*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*0328*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*0330*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*0338*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*0340*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*0348*/         FFMA R26, R22, R8, R26;                           /* 0x3034000021669c00 */
/*0350*/         LD.E R22, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001059c85 */
/*0358*/         FFMA R8, R23, R9, R26;                            /* 0x3034000025721c00 */
/*0360*/         LD.E R23, [R18];                                  /* 0x840000000125dc85 */
/*0368*/         IADD R16.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039441c03 */
/*0370*/         IADD.X R17, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d545c43 */
/*0378*/         FFMA R8, R24, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029821c00 */
/*0380*/         LD.E R24, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001461c85 */
/*0388*/         FFMA R26, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d969c00 */
/*0390*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0398*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x40];                               /* 0xc100000103f21cc5 */
/*03a0*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*03a8*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*03b0*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*03b8*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*03c0*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*03c8*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*03d0*/         FFMA R26, R22, R8, R26;                           /* 0x3034000021669c00 */
/*03d8*/         LD.E R22, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001059c85 */
/*03e0*/         FFMA R8, R23, R9, R26;                            /* 0x3034000025721c00 */
/*03e8*/         LD.E R23, [R18];                                  /* 0x840000000125dc85 */
/*03f0*/         IADD R16.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039441c03 */
/*03f8*/         LD.E R20, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001451c85 */
/*0400*/         IADD.X R17, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d545c43 */
/*0408*/         FFMA R8, R24, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029821c00 */
/*0410*/         FFMA R24, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d961c00 */
/*0418*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*0420*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x50];                               /* 0xc100000143f21cc5 */
/*0428*/         IADD R16.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039041c03 */
/*0430*/         IADD.X R17, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d145c43 */
/*0438*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*0440*/         LD.E R21, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001055c85 */
/*0448*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*0450*/         IADD R16.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039241c03 */
/*0458*/         IADD.X R17, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d345c43 */
/*0460*/         FFMA R8, R22, R8, R24;                            /* 0x3030000021621c00 */
/*0468*/         LD.E R24, [R18];                                  /* 0x8400000001261c85 */
/*0470*/         FFMA R8, R23, R9, R8;                             /* 0x3010000025721c00 */
/*0478*/         IADD R18.CC, R16, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039049c03 */
/*0480*/         FFMA R8, R20, R10, R8;                            /* 0x3010000029421c00 */
/*0488*/         IADD.X R19, R17, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d14dc43 */
/*0490*/         IADD R20.CC, R18, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039251c03 */
/*0498*/         LD.E R18, [R18];                                  /* 0x8400000001249c85 */
/*04a0*/         FFMA R22, R25, R11, R8;                           /* 0x301000002d959c00 */
/*04a8*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x60];                               /* 0xc100000183f21cc5 */
/*04b0*/         LD.E R25, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001065c85 */
/*04b8*/         FFMA R16, R21, R8, R22;                           /* 0x302c000021541c00 */
/*04c0*/         IADD.X R21, R19, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d355c43 */
/*04c8*/         IADD R22.CC, R20, R14;                            /* 0x4801000039459c03 */
/*04d0*/         LD.E R20, [R20];                                  /* 0x8400000001451c85 */
/*04d8*/         IADD.X R23, R21, R15;                             /* 0x480000003d55dc43 */
/*04e0*/         IADD R8.CC, R22, R14;                             /* 0x4801000039621c03 */
/*04e8*/         LD.E R22, [R22];                                  /* 0x8400000001659c85 */
/*04f0*/         FFMA R24, R24, R9, R16;                           /* 0x3020000025861c00 */
/*04f8*/         IADD.X R9, R23, R15;                              /* 0x480000003d725c43 */
/*0500*/         IADD R16.CC, R8, R14;                             /* 0x4801000038841c03 */
/*0508*/         LD.E R19, [R8];                                   /* 0x840000000084dc85 */
/*0510*/         IADD.X R17, R9, R15;                              /* 0x480000003c945c43 */
/*0518*/         LD.E R21, [R16];                                  /* 0x8400000001055c85 */
/*0520*/         FFMA R24, R25, R10, R24;                          /* 0x3030000029961c00 */
/*0528*/         FFMA R18, R18, R11, R24;                          /* 0x303000002d249c00 */
/*0530*/         LDS.128 R8, [0x70];                               /* 0xc1000001c3f21cc5 */
/*0538*/         FFMA R18, R20, R8, R18;                           /* 0x3024000021449c00 */
/*0540*/         IADD R8.CC, R16, R14;                             /* 0x4801000039021c03 */
/*0548*/         FFMA R9, R22, R9, R18;                            /* 0x3024000025625c00 */
/*0550*/         FFMA R10, R19, R10, R9;                           /* 0x3012000029329c00 */
/*0558*/         IADD.X R9, R17, R15;                              /* 0x480000003d125c43 */
/*0560*/         FFMA R20, R21, R11, R10;                          /* 0x301400002d551c00 */
/*0568*/         BAR.RED.POPC RZ, RZ, RZ, PT;                      /* 0x50ee0000ffffdc04 */
/*0570*/         IADD R7.CC, R7, 0x1;                              /* 0x4801c0000471dc03 */
/*0578*/         IADD.X R13, R13, RZ;                              /* 0x48000000fcd35c43 */
/*0580*/         ISUB RZ.CC, R7, R4;                               /* 0x48010000107fdd03 */
/*0588*/         ISETP.LT.U32.X.AND P0, PT, R13, R5, PT;           /* 0x188e000014d1dc43 */
/*0590*/         IADD R2.CC, R2, 0x80;                             /* 0x4801c00200209c03 */
/*0598*/         IADD.X R3, R3, RZ;                                /* 0x48000000fc30dc43 */
/*05a0*/     @P0 BRA 0x110;                                        /* 0x4003ffeda00001e7 */
```

Due to SO character count limits, I've had to just excerpt from each kernel the "main loop" that is doing the actual matrix-vector multiply arithmetic.  This is performed by `FFMA` instructions - floating point fused multiply-add.  If you look at the matrix-vector multiply arithmetic, you will see that it is a sequence of multiply-add operations.

Comparing the above 2 cases, we can make a few observations:

1. The slower kernel has just a single `FFMA` instruction in the entire kernel - and it is in the loop I have shown.  In order to perform 32 multiply-add operations, the loop must execute 32 times.  The faster kernel had 32 separate `FFMA` instructions in it.  This is what is called "unrolled".  The loop from the previous kernel is gone.  Therefore that instruction sequence need only execute once to perform all 32 necessary multiply-add operations.
2. Consistent with the unrolling, we see that the slower ("rolled up") code has about 11 instructions in the loop.  The unrolled code has ~150 instructions.
3. Since the rolled-up code must execute 32 times, it's as if 32x11 or about 350 instructions need to be executed.  Comparing this to the unrolled case, we see that only half as many instructions must be executed.

This then could be a hand-waving explanation for at least a 2x performance difference between the 2 cases.  Since the unrolled loop gives the compiler better opportunity to combine intermediate steps, it can reduce the overall instruction count, by optimizing over larger sections of code than what the loop affords.  There is also probably some benefit from the fact that the unrolled code requires no branching at all during the execution of the 32 `FFMA` instructions.

> Also given this situation, how am i supposed to get the max out of my kernel using all the different blocksizes i want? I can't do this thing for all the blocksizes...

Well, how many block sizes are there, actually, of true interest?  Usual cuda recommendations involve block sizes that are multiples of 32 or even binary powers of 2, that are "not too small" and "not too large".  For a real world vector-matrix multiply, you might only need to worry about several block sizes, such as 64, 128, 256, and 512.  You could just hand-write those, but *templating* might be another approach for actually a lot of flexibility here, for this particular substitution that you are concerned about.  Something like this:

```
template <int BS>
__global__ void dmv_gpu_shmem_templ(const float *a, const float *x, float *y,
                              size_t n)
{
    extern __shared__ float shmem_buf[];
    int ltid = threadIdx.x;
    int gtid = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    float _y = 0.0;

    if (gtid > n)
        return;

    int last_id = n/BS;

    for(size_t j=0; j< last_id; j++) {

        shmem_buf[ltid] = x[BS*j + ltid];
        __syncthreads();

        for(size_t i=0; i< BS; i++) {
            _y += a[gtid + (i + j*BS)*n] * shmem_buf[i];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    y[gtid] = _y;

}
```

and:

```
if(gpu_block == 32)
  dmv_gpu_shmem_templ<32><<<gpu_grid,gpu_block,shmem_size>>>
    (gpu_A, gpu_x, gpu_y, n);
```

Comment: Until you replied, i was kind of heading to the same direction, but your answer is really spot-on explaining every single detail that i was missing. Thanks a lot.